# IE8 error assigning a function() to a property name 'function'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

Consider running the following code in IE8 and Chrome consoles to compare:

```
var a = function(){ console.log("function is() initialized"); };

// assign a property named 'function' to function 'a'

a.function = function afunction(f){ return (typeof f === 'function'? true: false); };

// Use our is function to test if a given variable is a function

a.function(a); // IE throws 'expected identifier' error v/s Chrome correctly outputs "true"
```

Any ideas how this can be tackled in IE8 without changing function signature: a.function()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the alternate property access syntax, which is immune to interference from reserved words:

```
a["function"](a);
```

Comment: I raised a followup question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25532175/405117). Thanks for your time!